# Comsol resistive heating coil simulation

Tags: comsol, mems

I have a resistive coil from a MEMS. The only data I have to simulate the resistive heating is the input voltage which I can use between 0.5V to 20V and the material of the coil(GOLD). I am getting error like [Failed to find a solution.
System matrix is zero.
Returned solution is not converged.]. How would someone perform simulation with this amount of data and the given cad model.

Comment: Describe in more details what have you done.

Comment: I have resistive layer on silicon substrate of 10µm². the resistive coil is has a high aspect ratio, it is 500nm in high and 100µm in width. i have used Joule heating physics and applied electric potential on one boundary of 10V and gave ground on the other end. I applied heat flux boundary for the all domains from heat transfer in solids physic. With meshing done right. I tried to compute the study but got errors - 1. segregation error, 2. solution not converged. I tried this study with help of comsol tutorials avaliable on comsol page but still didn't got desired results.